# Django 2.x Primary-Key to UUID field

Tags: python, django, primary-key, uuid

I don't want my site to use integer id's as primary-key's because they are easy to determine by simyply doing i+1
instead i want to use UUID fields for that. So i started to add an UUIDField as id field on all my models like this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
...
```

but since i did that i get errors like:

> Reverse for 'profile' with keyword arguments '{'pk':
>   UUID('68065cdb-c611-4865-bffc-32e00421bef1')}' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: ['user/(?P\d+)/profile$']

my urls.py looks like:

```
url(r'^user/(?P<pk>\d+)/profile$', auth_required(app.view_profile_external), name='profile'),
```

template.html:

```
....
<div>
   <a href="{% url 'profile' pk=user.pk %}">My Profile</a>
</div>
....
```

views.py

```
def view_profile_external(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=pk)
    else:
        user = request.user
    args = {'external_user': user}
    return render(request, 'app/profile_as_external.html', args)
```

do i need to change something here also? I don't get it why the UUIDField is not resolveable the same way as the Integer field as pk or id provided by django as default.

Comment: Change the url to `url(r'^user/(?P<pk>[0-9a-f-]+)/profile$'`. Bcz UUID contains digits alphabets `-` s. Currently it is matching only digits

Comment: Simply flawless! Thanks for this very potent hint :D
If you write an answer for this I will mark it as solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reverse on uuid using the uuid [path converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters):

```
path('user/<uuid:pk>/profile$', auth_required(app.view_profile_external), name='profile'),
```

or if you're on Django 1.11:

```
r_uuid = r'[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}'

url(r'^user/(?P<pk>%s)/profile$' % r_uuid, auth_required(app.view_profile_external), name='profile')
```